# Why is this code not changing the background-image as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have this JQuery code (in a file called **home_main_post.js**):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    searchQuery();
});
function searchQuery() {
    var searchBoxIcon = $('i.main.search.link.icon');
    var searchInput = $('.prompt.search-box');
    searchBoxIcon.click(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)), url(../Images/library_background.png)');
    })
}
```

Now the problem is that when I click on the search button I have, it changes the background but only the linear gradient is applied. The rest is white. I think it is not being able to locate the image. My folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

I have also tried `./Images/.....`, `/Images/.....` but to no avail.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a absolute path like `url(http://placehold.it/64/fff000)`

Comment: Also check your browser dev tools -> network tab to see what is the image URL requested

Comment: why not add a class to `body` and handle everything in CSS?

Comment: @skip405 I need to change the background on clicking a button.

Comment: yes, `.click($(body).addClass('body-with-a-different-background'))` and in CSS - `.body-with-a-different-background { background: red }`

Comment: @skip405 I did not understand it the first time. Yes that's a good solution. Thanks. *But* why is my code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the library_background has a `.jpg` format please view and also i see that you highlighted the home_background which has the `.png` format please change the formats or the image 
 hope this helps,
 thnx.